# What is this movie featuring a grey giant monster/man in an exoskeleton?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I just had a memory out of nowhere of a movie scene I watched long ago, the movie scene as I remember went like this:

A giant grey/steel coloured (either it was wearing an exoskeleton or its skin colour was grey/steel) monster was running over the roof of houses trying to evade capture and at one point busted through a metal gate. Eventually the pursuers surround him and each pursuer whips out a leash with which they capture the monster/man in exoskeleton. The setting of the movie seemed old i.e the movie was not set in modern times maybe somewhere 1700's or 1800's maybe. Very vaguely but I think there was a scene set in a place like Venice (not exactly Venice) because the streets had water and buildings were around it.

As a kid I only watched Marvel cartoons and read Marvel comics and hence as a child when I watched it I initially  considered the monster/man in exoskeleton as Iron Man or Grey Hulk because it was huge like Hulk or the original Iron Man suit, but it was certainly not a Marvel movie.

The movie was live action, in English.  As for the science fiction elements, inclusion of a huge grey couloured/man in exoskeleton would suffice. I can't date the production year. I saw it around 2014-2015 on TV but the movie felt much older.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include approximately what year and in what country/language you saw this movie.

Comment: Sounds a bit like Mr. Hyde's introductory scene in _The League of Extraordinary Gentlemen_ (2003). Doesn't quite match your description though.

Comment: I would suggest The League of Extraordinary Gentlemen (2003), which has a scene with Hyde running across rooftops to evade capture, and a later sequence in Venice. However, Hyde does not have gray skin or an exoskeleton, so I don't think this is it.

Comment: One could mistake Hyde for having an exoskeleton, based on the change in physique between him and Jekyll.  OP, was there a huge submarine as well?

Comment: @ZeissIkon, I dont actually remeber a scene with a submarine

Answer (score 5):

Is this ***[The League of Extraordinary Gentlemen](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0311429/)*** (2003)...?

> In an alternate Victorian Age world, a group of famous contemporary fantasy, science fiction, and adventure characters team up on a secret mission.

At a little over 30 minutes into the runtime, Mr. Hyde is shown running across Parisian rooftops, attempting to evade capture by Allan Quartermain and Tom Sawyer, who're pursuing him at ground level, using gunshots to steer him toward a trap. Hyde doesn't bust through a metal gate and isn't grey-skinned, but he is wearing a torn black suit and hat and is dimly-lit, as the scene takes place at night. This depiction of the character also has a physique similar to the Hulk's. He eventually falls into the trap, which is a net that drags him onto Captain Nemo's submarine, the Nautilus. We aren't shown who or what was pulling the net.

The next time we see Hyde, he's in a compartment inside the submarine and is partially bound by several chains which are attached to the walls. He's also surrounded by a group of Nemo's crewmen, who're wielding spears in an attempt to hem him in, since he isn't yet fully restrained.

Comment: It has been some time since I watched this movie but I don't think this it, if it had been Mr Hyde I must have remembered but still I'll rewatch the movie to confirm.